# How to add custom point of interest with the google maps sdk on android

Tags: android, database, geolocation

I am looking for a way to add my own lat/long markers on the map for my android app. I tried looking up the places api documentation, but really couldn't wrap my mind around how it should look like. The idea is to be able to feed the app a lat/long tuple, save it in a database and then allow other users to get a hold of this information in the form of a marker on their MapView. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Location Manager to fetch current latitude and longitude.

```
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double long = location.getLongitude();

Latlang start = new LatLng(lat, long);
```

Then add marker as:

```
 MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(start);
        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_start_blue));
        mMap.addMarker(options);
```

Then animate the camera at that point.